# Get id of element on button and auto click using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to autosubmit a single button on a page that may have a selection of multiple buttons. The challenge is that the buttons do not have a name or ID reference, and rather, each input element uses a "tabindex=n" ID. The quick and easy would have been to add a unique Name or ID to the form, but we do not have access to the server side code so it must all be done client side.

I've tried various approaches but none seem to help so here's the form code...

```
<div tabindex="1" class="dp" onkeypress="if (event &amp;&amp; (event.keyCode == 32 || event.keyCode == 13)) RD.selection('http://node.blankplanet.com');" onclick="RD.selection('http://node.blankplanet.com/'); return false;">
  <img class="largeIcon float" alt="Node..." src="/images/local.png?id=3B194F1192F038FFF32BF9C4AFF16AA1859EC1D2462FB845BC9813C490A994BB">
  <div class="Description float">
    <span class="largeTextNoWrap indentNonCollapsible">Node..</span>
  </div>
</div>    

<div tabindex="2" class="dp" onkeypress="if (event &amp;&amp; (event.keyCode == 32 || event.keyCode == 13)) RD.selection('http://node2.blankplanet.com/');" onclick="RD.selection('http://node2.blankplanet.com/'); return false;">
  <img class="largeIcon float" alt="Node2..." src="/images/dp.png?id=D29E7325C0DB2C8C6DE5B6632374C52A6975B90CA5FCB6F05F801496191334AF">      
  <div class="dpDescription float">
    <span class="largeTextNoWrap indentNonCollapsible">Node2...</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div tabindex="3" class="dp" onkeypress="if (event &amp;&amp; (event.keyCode == 32 || event.keyCode == 13)) RD.selection('http://node3.blankplanet.com');" onclick="RD.selection('http://node3.blankplanet.com/'); return false;">
  <img class="largeIcon float" alt="Node3..." src="/images/dp.png?id=D29E7325C0DB2C8C6DE5B6632374C52A6975B90CA5FCB6F05F801496191334AF">      
  <div class="dpDescription float">
    <span class="largeTextNoWrap indentNonCollapsible">Node3...</span> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what exactly is it you want to do? I don't see any `<inputs>` or `<buttons>` in your code, and no `id`'s either. So what 'ID' is it that you want to get? To get click events on the divs, `$('div[tabindex]').click(function(){...});` would work...

Answer (score 0):

if you want to autosubmit say button 2 then you would want to use following selector:

```
$('div[tabindex=2]').click();
```

try around here:
http://jsfiddle.net/85h3gtnj/1/

actually to make sure you hit no other divs you should add the class selector

```
$('div.dp[tabindex=2]').click();
```

as fiddled here:
http://jsfiddle.net/85h3gtnj/3/

Comment: Thanks folks, all great answers and this last suggestion did the trick perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

If the tabindex is the attribute that is set reliably on the page, you can use that to call the click() event:

```
$.each('div', function() {
    if ($(this).attr('tablindex') == 4) {
        $(this).click(); //makes it submit
    }
});
```

you can also call the div using the nth-child selector:

```
$('#container div:nth-child(4)').click();
```

Info on nth-child can be found here: https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

is that what u need? FIddle: https://jsfiddle.net/288er5td/

CODE:

```
<div tabindex="1" class="dp" >
    <img class="largeIcon float" alt="Node..." src="/images/local.png?id=3B194F1192F038FFF32BF9C4AFF16AA1859EC1D2462FB845BC9813C490A994BB" />
  <div class="Description float">
            <input data-input-field='' type='text' val ='val1' />
    <span class="largeTextNoWrap indentNonCollapsible">Node..</span>
  </div>
</div>    

<div tabindex="2" class="dp">
    <img class="largeIcon float" alt="Node2..." src="/images/dp.png?id=D29E7325C0DB2C8C6DE5B6632374C52A6975B90CA5FCB6F05F801496191334AF" />      
  <div class="dpDescription float">
      <input data-input-field='' type='text' val ='val2' />
    <span class="largeTextNoWrap indentNonCollapsible">Node2...</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div tabindex="3" class="dp">
    <img class="largeIcon float" alt="Node3..." src="/images/dp.png?id=D29E7325C0DB2C8C6DE5B6632374C52A6975B90CA5FCB6F05F801496191334AF" />      
  <div class="dpDescription float">
            <input data-input-field='' type='text' val ='val3' />
    <span class="largeTextNoWrap indentNonCollapsible">Node3...</span> 
  </div>
</div>


$(document).ready(function(){
    t = function(elem){
        var $this = elem;
        var $tab = $this.closest('.dp');
        var tabindex = $tab.attr('tabindex');
        var i_val = $this.val();
        alert(tabindex);
        alert(i_val);
    }
    $(document).on('click', '[data-input-field]', function(){
        t($(this));

    });
    $(document).on('keypress', '[data-input-field]', function(event){
        if ((event.keyCode == 32) || (event.keyCode == 13)){
            t($(this));
        }     
    });
});
```